# New default sort order for Stack Overflow home page?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, sorting, homepage

I wasn't aware of changing any settings or deleting any cookies.  What happened to the default sort order of questions with the latest activity?

Comment: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/stack-overflow-homepage-changes/

Answer (score 1):

The blog entry [Stack Overflow Homepage Changes](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/stack-overflow-homepage-changes/) explains what's going on.